# I want to find the first quartile in which the mentioned condition is satisfied but i am facing this error

Tags: python, pandas

```
x=[ ]

for i,row in enumerate (df3['GDP']):

        if((df3.iloc[i]<df3.iloc[i-1]) & (df3.iloc[i+1]<df3.iloc[i])):
            x.append(i)

print(x)
```

> 

It is showing this 
   ERROR The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

[image: Here's a sample of my data]

Comment: @piRSquared i am a noob in programming and through those 2 questions I couldn't figure out my problem. I would be highly grateful if you would remove this mark as duplicate tag and answer my question

Comment: You've got a few things wrong with your code.  We can help more if you tell us what you are trying to do.  The question and answers I linked answers the question of why you are getting the error.  However, it seems you want to know how to accomplish some task, which is more than the question you asked.  You'd be better served, as would the community, if you clarified what it is you are trying to do, what you expect as a result, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: i want to find out the quartile which satisfies the mentioned condition

Comment: You should click the [***edit***](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43291830/edit) link and make you question as clear as possible.  Also, if you want to use SO as a resource, read [***MCVE***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [***HowToAsk***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:
You want the ordinal positions of where the `'GDP'` values were greater than the last one and less then the next one.

Consider the dataframe `df3`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dict(GDP=np.random.randint(10, size=15)))

print(df3)

    GDP
0     0
1     2
2     7
3     3
4     8
5     7
6     0
7     6
8     8
9     6
10    0
11    2
12    0
13    4
14    9
```

***solution***
using `shift`

```
g = df3.GDP
x = np.arange(len(g))[g.gt(g.shift()) & g.lt(g.shift(-1))]
print(x)

[ 1  7 13]
```

---

The answer to your actual question is that you can't assess the truth of a `pd.DataFrame` or `pd.Series` and that's exactly what you were trying to do with

```
if((df3.iloc[i]<df3.iloc[i-1]) & (df3.iloc[i+1]<df3.iloc[i])):
```

Comment: What do you mean by I can't assess the truth of a dataframe?

Comment: take the `pd.Series` `g` referenced in my asnwer. `g > 3` evaluates to a `pd.Series` of `True`s and `False`s.  It isn't `True` or `False` on it's own.  `bool(g > 3)` returns the same error you asked about.  You get it because `pandas` recognizes when `bool(pd.Series)` is called and raises that exception.  It does this because it makes no sense to ask if the series of boolean values is itself `True` or `False`.  People fall into this trap as they are looking to iterate over the series of booleans and they mistakenly evaluate the whole series.